# Where to write the * in declaration?

Tags: c++

Mahlzeit community,

i've a new question :D

Does it makes any difference where i write the `*` when i wanna declarate a pointer?

E.g.

```
void loopsWithCStringsV2()
{
    const char*  str1 = "i love learning";
    const char * str2 = "i love learning";
    const char  *str3 = "i love learning";
    
    std::cout << "str1: " << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str2: " << str2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str3: " << str3 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "&str1: " << &str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&str2: " << &str2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&str3: " << &str3 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "*str1: " << *str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*str2: " << *str2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*str3: " << *str3 << std::endl;
}
```

will result in:

```
str1: i love learning
str2: i love learning
str3: i love learning
&str1: 006FFAA8
&str2: 006FFA9C
&str3: 006FFA90
*str1: i
*str2: i
*str3: i
```

Enjoy your day :)

Comment: No. White spaces are mostly ignored

Comment: No it doesn't. Formally it's `const char *str1;` although it's been the fashion for years to regard it as `const char* str1`.

Comment: `*` is a token that doesn't require whitespace, so it doesn't matter. You can even do abomination like `const char*str4`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I had a quant who insisted on doing that. Now works in model validation.

Comment: You can even write `const`, `char`, `*`, and e.g. `str1` all on different lines (as well as the `=` and the string literal).

Comment: there are good points for either: The `*` is part of the type not of the name, hence `int* x;` on the other hand, actually the grammer rules say that `*` belongs to `x` not to `int` which matters if you have more than one in a line, hence `int *x,*y;`. I am sure there are duplicates...

Comment: @idclev463035818: There are dupes out there for this one, hence nobody dares answer this.

Comment: fwiw, I just checked the [core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and they don't mention it, though all their examples use the convention of one declaration per line and the convention to put the `*` next to the type

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That's meaningless. The only tokens that *do* require whitespace are identifiers and numeric literals.

Comment: @idclev463035818 If you consider the meanings of `char *a,b;` and `char *a,*b` you will see that the `*` is associated with the identifier, not the preceding type name.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne thats exactly what I wrote, no?

Comment: I just discovered that the input field when "closing as duplicate" accepts not just an URL, but also works as a search.

Comment: @MSalters it just needs a default filter for the questions tags and i'd be happy

Comment: Heyho,
@MarquisofLorne
 so this means that {code}char *a, b;{code} would be a variable 
a: a pointer to a char 
b: a char

and 

{code}char *a,*b{code} would be

a: a pointer to a char
b: a pointer to a char

so in other words.. the asterics is associated with the following "word" in the declaration?

correct me if i'm wrong.. please ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Does it makes any difference where i write the * when i wanna declarate a pointer?

Yes, the placement of * matters. For example, these are wrong:

```
*const char  str1 = "i love learning";
const* char  str1 = "i love learning";
const char  str1 = "i love learning";*
```

---

> ```
> const char*  str1 = "i love learning";
> const char * str2 = "i love learning";
> const char  *str3 = "i love learning";
> ```

Whitespace around * has no effect. In most cases whitespace has little significance in C++, except to separate tokens such as keywords from other text. All of the above are the same.

Comment: You mean "No" right?

Comment: @Bathsheba No. Placement of * matters. The whitespace doesn't.

Comment: ...but OP only considers `const char* str1` vs `const char *str` if you refer to `const char* str` vs `const * char str` you should mention it, currently its not quite clear

Comment: @idclev463035818 Added clarification.

Comment: Got it. Nice answer. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.
In your example it doesn't make any difference.
Moreover, you can write something like this, and it will behave the same way:

```
const char*str1 = "i love learning";
```

**BUT** actually there is another case when the location of the "*" makes a huge difference.
It's when you write the pointer * before the char and after the char.
e.g. `const * char str1` vs `const char * str1`
In one case you'd get a constant pointer to a char, and in another case you'd get a pointer to a constant char.
For more details check this:
[What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)